# Regex/Python: Find everything before one symbol, if it's after another symbol

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Looking to return a full string after if there is a long dash ("―"), and if true, return everything before the first comma (","). How would I do this using Python with Regex?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

request = requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/fun?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')
# for loop
s = soup.find_all("div", class_="quoteText")[0].text
s = " ".join(s.split()) 
s[:s.index(",")]
s
```

Raw Output:

```
“That does it," said Jace. "I\'m going to get you a dictionary for Christmas this year.""Why?" Isabelle said."So you can look up \'fun.\' I\'m not sure you know what it means.” ― Cassandra Clare, City of Ashes //<![CDATA[ function submitShelfLink(unique_id, book_id, shelf_id, shelf_name, submit_form, exclusive) { var checkbox_id = \'shelf_name_\' + unique_id + \'_\' + shelf_id; var element = document.getElementById(checkbox_id) var checked = element.checked if (checked && exclusive) { // can\'t uncheck a radio by clicking it! return } if(document.getElementById("savingMessage")){ Element.show(\'savingMessage\') } var element_id = \'shelfInDropdownName_\' + unique_id + \'_\' + shelf_id; Element.upda
```

Desired Output:

```
“That does it," said Jace. "I\'m going to get you a dictionary for Christmas this year.""Why?" Isabelle said."So you can look up \'fun.\' I\'m not sure you know what it means.” ― Cassandra Clare
```

Comment: This is slightly more difficult as the text you want is stored in multiple tags and needs to be collated. If you go through the tags logically, you won't need a regex at all - I'll take a look at the source in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
import re

s = 'adflakjd, fkljlkjdf ― Cassandra Clare, City of Ash, adflak'

x = re.findall('.*―.*?(?=,)', s)


print x

['adflakjd, fkljlkjdf ― Cassandra Clare']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand it properly, but I think you mean:

```
example_string = "part to return,example__text"
if example_string.count('__') > 0:
    try:
        result = re.search('(.*?)\,', example_string).group(0)
    except:
        result = None
print(result)
```

This prints 'part to return'

If you mean, the part of the string between the '__' and the ',' I would use:

```
example_string = "lala__part to return, lala"
try:
    result = re.search('__(.*?)\,', example_string).group(0)
except:
    result = None
print(result)
```

Comment: It's after the long dash.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString
import requests


request = requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/fun?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')
# for loop
s = soup.find_all("div", class_="quoteText")[0]

text = ''

text += "".join([t.strip() for t in s.contents if type(t) == NavigableString])

for book_or_author_tag in s.find_all("a", class_ = "authorOrTitle"):
    text += "\n" + book_or_author_tag.text.strip()

print(text)
```

The quote you want is split across the initial quoteText div, but calling `text` on it returns all that CDATA junk you're trying to remove with the regex.

By looping over every child of that div and checking whether it's a navigable string type, we can extract only the actual text data you want. then tack on the author and book, and hopefully your regex becomes a lot simpler.

Comment: This is a very practical solution. However, I couldn't get it working across multiple quotes.

Comment: @BobHopez I had copied your code, so the initial soup.find_all()[0] only returns the first quote div. Remove the [0] and then loop over each div, and you should get them all.